# Only one of external monitors works (Lenovo T480 on Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, 18.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have two external monitors connected to Lenovo T480 via USB-C and HDMI ports (no adapters).
The system only detects builtin and external monitor connected via USB-C, the one connected via HDMI - turns black and nothing happens. But when I unplug USB-C monitor, then HDMI one starts working and the system recognizes it.
Btw closing the lid didn't help - the situation is the same - only USB-C works (HDMI works only if USB-C disconnected).

`lspci -v | grep -i vga`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

`lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:154 memory:e7000000-e7ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`xrandr` with USB-C connected (HDMI connected):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192                         
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm        
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00                           
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88                                                               
   1600x1024     60.17                                                                        
   1400x1050     59.98                                                                        
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82                                             
   1280x1024     60.02                                                                        
   1440x900      59.89                                                                        
   1400x900      59.96    59.88                                                               
   1280x960      60.00           
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`xrandr` with USB-C disconnected (HDMI connected):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm                                                   

   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00                                                                                                                           
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88                                                                                                                                                               
   1600x1024     60.17                                                                                                                                                                        
   1400x1050     59.98                                                                                                                                                                        
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82                                                                                                                                             
   1280x1024     60.02                                                                                                                                                                        
   1440x900      59.89                                                                                                                                                                        
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm I am experiencing the exact same issue with a t480s

Comment: I have a similar issue when my T480s when it's connected to the dock. They are all connected and visible from system settings, but there is no picture on the third monitor

Comment: I have the same issue with T440s with dock, with two different monitors and DP and HDMI. xrandr also looks fine. Seems like there is an serious error.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue (even though I use Windows) on the T480 using a USB-C hub with HDMI, power and other USB ports.

In *my* case, the problem was I was using the wrong USB-C port. I was using the left-most USB-C which powers the laptop, instead of the second from the left which is the only Thunderbolt capable one.

Hope this helps, at least someone else who might come across this post.

Comment: Omg where can I buy you a beer?
This completely made my day. I didn't even realize the other slot on the T480 is USB-C, because it looks so weird.

Comment: @workflow You should first accept the answer that was helpful to you. Then go have all the beers you want.

Comment: @ChanganAuto How do I do that if I didn't ask the original question? I already upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a 65W power supply instead of 90. As soon as I swapped them out, functionality was as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with Lenovo T480s and dockstation thinkpad 135 W.

Workaround 1: Disable PageFlip for modesetting

It is preferred to keep using "modesetting" driver, but disabling page flipping is necessary. 
To do this, as a root user create a **file** **`20-displaylink.conf`** under:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "DisplayLink"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "PageFlip" "false"
EndSection
```

A reboot is required for the setting to be effective.

Source:
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

From:
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu

Steps to do it:

To create the file:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/

touch 20-displaylink.conf

sudo nano 20-displaylink.conf
```

paste the content

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "DisplayLink"
Driver "modesetting"
Option "PageFlip" "false"
EndSection
```

then

```
control + O
```

to save

then

```
control + x
```

to exit nano.

Then reboot is required for the setting to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get two external displays working along with the built-in display by purchasing two USB-C to HDMI converters and plugging them into the two USB-C ports. One of these converters also has a power-in so I can charge the laptop at the same time.

(I was NOT able to get a direct HDMI and USB-C display to work simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I helped to clarify the problem.

*"Do not connect external displays to the USB-C connector 1 and the HDMI connector 2 at the same time.
Otherwise, only the external display connected to the USB-C connector 1 will work by default. To change
the priority between the USB-C connector and the HDMI connector, start the ThinkPad Setup program.
See “” on page , and then configure Shared Display Priority in “” on page."*

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the official [DisplayLink](https://www.displaylink.com/) driver from their web site.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: How is this even relevant to OP's question? Also, if you mean the DisplayLink product, then it only works fine on Windows. Under linux it is just a garbage generating high cpu load.